# Selecting correct radio button in PHP from SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, forms, radio-button

I'm working on a bit of code to edit data from a database.  On the original form (which I am mimicking) it has a radio button group with 6 options for days :

```
 <label for="arrival">When will you arrive?</label><br />
    <input type="radio" id="pre" name="arrival" value="pre"/>Pre-KG<br />
    <input type="radio" id="wed" name="arrival" value="wed"/>Wednesday<br />
    <input type="radio" id="thu" name="arrival" value="thu"/>Thursday<br />
    <input type="radio" id="fri" name="arrival" value="fri"/>Friday<br />
    <input type="radio" id="sat" name="arrival" value="sat"/>Saturday<br />
    <input type="radio" id="sun" name="arrival" value="sun"/>Sunday<br />
```

I the put the value to the database after submission of the form.  Now I am calling the data from the database and I want to have the correct radio button selected.  Any suggestions on this?  I can't seem to find it by searching...

values are coming from an sql query to my database using $row["arrival"] with a value of one of the values above...

Previously for a yes/no option I used...

```
if ($row["costyn"]==1){
    echo '<input type="radio" name="costyn" value="1" checked>Yes<br>';
    echo '<input type="radio" name="costyn" value="0">No<br>';
    } else if ($row["costyn"]==0) {
    echo '<input type="radio" name="costyn" value="1" >Yes<br>';
    echo '<input type="radio" name="costyn" value="0" checked>No<br>';
    }
```

There must be a cleaner way though.

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: Where are you retrieving the value to match?

Comment: you need to put selected = selected on the one you've on the db

Comment: @MarcoMura For radio buttons it's `checked`, not `selected`.

Comment: @caCtus Right, too much work today o.o however if this radio isn't inside a loop he need to put a php if on each line or a Javascript that will "check" the correct radio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such case something like this may do the job:

```
<label for="arrival">When will you arrive?</label><br />
<?
$row["costyn"] = 4; // value from database

$radio_keys= array('pre', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun');
$radio_values = array('Pre-KG', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday');

foreach ($radio_keys as $key => $value) {
   echo '<input type="radio" name="arrival" value="'.$value.'" '.(($key+1)==$row["costyn"]?'checked':'').'/>'.$radio_values[$key].'<br />';
}
//ommited the ID, if you need it for JS/CSS reference you shall make it unique or use name/class for whole group.
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm and made total sense to me.  Appreciated!

Comment: Thanks, I updated the script for the output from database being a "number"

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP

firstly get which one you want to be checked then do this

lets say you have it as "pre"

```
$radio = "pre";
```

then

```
$checked[$radio] = "checked";
```

Your HTML

```
<label for="arrival">When will you arrive?</label><br />
<input type="radio" id="arrival1" name="arrival" value="pre" <?=(isset($checked['pre']))?$checked['pre']:"";>/>Pre-KG<br />
<input type="radio" id="arrival2" name="arrival" value="wed" <?=(isset($checked['wed']))?$checked['pre']:"";>/>Wednesday<br />
<input type="radio" id="arrival3" name="arrival" value="thu" <?=(isset($checked['thu']))?$checked['pre']:"";>/>Thursday<br />
<input type="radio" id="arrival4" name="arrival" value="fri" <?=(isset($checked['fri']))?$checked['pre']:"";>/>Friday<br />
<input type="radio" id="arrival5" name="arrival" value="sat" <?=(isset($checked['sat']))?$checked['pre']:"";>/>Saturday<br />
<input type="radio" id="arrival6" name="arrival" value="sun" <?=(isset($checked['sun']))?$checked['pre']:"";>/>Sunday<br />
```